# Configuration System failed to initialize - Windows Service .NET

Tags: .net, windows-services, .net-services

I created a .NET windows service that installs without any issues on the dev machine. On the server that has only the .NET framework (and no VS installed), since I don't have the VS 2008 prompt, I did the following.

1. I opened the command prompt
2. I did `cd C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727`
3. I attempted to install the service using `installutil.exe` "Path to the service .exe"

I get the following exception:

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version 2.0.50727.1433
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 
Configuration system failed to initialize
```

This service installs/uninstalls without any issues on my local host. Any help?

The service.exe.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Should process conversions -->
    <add key="Service.EnableConversions" value="true"/>
    <!-- Poll Interval-->
    <add key="Service.Interval" value="10000" /> <!-- Set to 10 seconds -->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was an issue with a corrupt machine.config on the server. After reinstalling it this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Received this error running InstallUtil.exe from the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 folder.  To fix, try copying the machine.config.default to machine.config (maybe backup your current machine.config if it is actually present in the Config directory).

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
copy machine.config.default machine.config
```

Now change to the parent directory and run InstallUtil.exe /? to see if it displays the usage info.

```
cd..
InstallUtil.exe /?
```

Hope this helps.
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your config should cause any trouble....

Can you try to create and install your service with the `sc.exe` tool instead? It's part of Windows and should be present on all more recent Windows versions.

Do a  `sc -?`  to get the full info about all the parameters.

Basically to create and install the service, you need:

```
sc create (service name) binPath= (path to your exe) DisplayName= (display name)
```

Watch for the **spaces** after the "=" sign! They're needed - without them, it won't work (I know it's odd - but that's the syntax - trust me).

Comment: Yes, the service.exe.config is the same folder as the service.exe